# Choose a record from the table where two of the default values are 0 or 1, a bit tricky

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for a more elegant and most logical solution for:

The table:

| index | id | by_default | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | AAA |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | ABA |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | ABC |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | BCA |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | BCB |

The task is to find the minimum index value with defaults set to 1 and/or defaults set to 0.

I have the following code (not very elegant, but it works, also very slow):

```
declare @byd_1 as int=
(select min(t.index) idx from Table t where t.[id]=1 and t.by_default=1)
declare @byd_2 as int=
(select min(t.index) idx from Table t where t.[id]=1 and t.by_default=0)
select (case when @byd_1 is null then @byd_2 else @byd_1 end)
```

The tricky part is: sometimes the by_default column is always 0 (for example: id:2 may have no by_default values set) and as mentioned earlier the task is: need to get the minimum value of the index column.

What is the most elegant (one-line) code possible?
Using MSSQL
The expected results, according to the sample table, should be the following:

| index | id | by_default | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | ABA |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | BCA |

Comment: Please include the expected output as well.

Comment: .... and tag the DBMS which you're currently using ...

Comment: Do you need minimum value of index groupby id and by_default,
select min(index) from Table group by id,by_default;

Comment: @anunaki in that case you will get two records as output: if id=1 then index rows (1,2) according to my sample table, expected the only one record: index=2

Answer (score 0):

Edited to add text also.

A bit ugly but:

```sql
drop table #t
select *
into #t
from (
    VALUES  (1, 1, 0, N'AAA')
    ,   (2, 1, 1, N'ABA')
    ,   (3, 1, 0, N'ABC')
    ,   (4, 2, 0, N'BCA')
    ,   (5, 2, 0, N'BCB')
) t (index_,id,by_default,text)

select index_, id, by_default, text
from (
    select  min(index_) OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS minIndex
    ,   MIN(case when by_default = 1 then index_ end) over(partition by id) AS minIndexDefault
    ,   *  
    from #t
    ) t
where isnull(minIndexDefault, minIndex) = index_
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't give the required result.

Comment: The expected results , according to the sample table, should be the following:
index: 1 title: ABA
index: 4 title: BCA

Comment: Sorry, but there are still no correct results for your query

Comment: Well, the result i get when running is exactly like your screenshot. so if it doesn't work, then i guess i'm out :)